# How to make a function in DB2 ibm to sum fields 01 to 06 in month 5? 01-07 in month6 and so on...

Tags: db2, sum

We have a database that stores the bank account of our clients like this:

```
|client|c01|c02|c03|c04|d01|d02|d03|d04|
|a     |3€ |5€ |4€ |0€ |-2€|-1€|-4€| 0€|
```

This is the structure of the database when we are in the month 3. In month 4 would be:

```
|client|c01|c02|c03|c04|c05|d01|d02|d03|d04|d05|
|a     |3€ |5€ |4€ |2€ |0€ |-2€|-1€|-4€|-2€| 0€|
```

take attention on the c05 and d05.

The database auto-updates adds those columns.
Because of this changing in the columns I can't get the sum of c01, c02, c03, c04, d01, d02, d03, d04 easily. I was thinking of making a function that checks the current month and makes a loop in order to select and sum those columns without errors.

If you have a better idea to do it, you are welcome. 
But the main question is how to make a function that is able to sum a variable number of columns?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something about adding a column every month that bugs me.  I know it can be a valid OLAP strategy as selective de-normalization, but it just feels wierd here.  Usually with these kinds of things, the entire width is specified, if for no other reason than to avoid `ALTER TABLE` statements.  I don't know enough about what you're storing there to give a recommendation otherwise, but I guess I just prefer fully normalized structures.

Having done similar endeavours, your best bet will be to use dynamic sql.  You can place that inside your stored procedure, `PREPARE`ing and `EXECUTE`ing as normal.

Comment: Can you explain with more detail the last part? (I'm only using db2 sometimes and I don't know much about it...) thanks

Comment: anyway I find another way to do it, I sum each individual row, instead of using the totals table.. it's easier

Comment: @Totty - If you have the original rows (and the performance is acceptable), it's usually best to go off those, instead of summed rows.

Comment: the performance is more or less, but this is not a critical app, therefore I don't worry about it. but thanks for your answer. Anyway it would be interesting to know how to make the sum on variable cols based on the current date..